# Changing a defined column using sqlalchemy into a longer-length unicode

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a table defined in my app like this:

```
users = Table('users', metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True),
    Column('user_name', Unicode(16), unique=True, nullable=False),
    Column('email_address', Unicode(255), unique=True, nullable=False),
    Column('display_name', Unicode(255)),
    Column('password', Unicode(80)),
    Column('created', DateTime, default=datetime.now),
    mysql_engine='InnoDB',
    mysql_charset='utf8',
)
```

However, after developing for a while, I want to change user_name to a longer length, such as Unicode(255). As I understand it, this definition is run at first start-up, and so just changing this line wouldn't work for existing databases. It needs to migrate to this new definition. How do I go about converting already created databases into the new, desired definition?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE` doesn't work?

Comment: Looking up the syntax for this..

Comment: alter table users modify user_name xxx; now I'm not sure what xxx should be VARCHAR(255)?

Comment: Probably .. I didn't even know `Unicode` was a data type

Comment: Documentation for sqlalchemy indicates Unicode type is NVARCHAR, or maybe it depends on the database. Thanks http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_0_6/core/types.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that updating your code will not update an existing database schema. You can use Alembic to auto-generate and run schema migrations. Alembic can auto-generate change scripts for you by comparing the schema of your newly edited metadata with the schema from your database. Start here: http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Edit `alembic/env.py` and modify your configuration to include `compare_type=True`:

```
def run_migrations_online():
    ...
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
            context.configure(
                connection=connection,
                target_metadata=target_metadata,
                compare_type=True, # <------------- THIS LINE HERE
            )
    ...
```

Disclosure, I got this solution from this [helpful guide](https://eshlox.net/2017/08/06/alembic-migration-for-string-length-change).